# Sublime Text Side Bar Activating every time when switching between open files. How can I stop it?

Tags: sublimetext3, sidebar

Basically:
Using Sublime Text: build 3114 on Win7

Every time when I move between open files in different tabs the side bar annoyingly keeps activating itself each time and keeps sliding in.

Is this a bug or am I missing some setting somewhere that I have to tweak?

Looked all over the place for an explanation/settings option but no luck.
I have Sublime on another Win7 machine and the sidebar behaves as expected. It doesn't activate itself when I move between open files.

Comment: if it is not the problem you talking about then i will try other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES!!! finally found what was doing it :)
An obscure plugin I had : *AutoHide Sidebar* , Uninstalled and all is good..finally...

Hope this helps anyone who gets in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

### you can hide side bar from view

---

[image: did you try this]

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but every time I switch between files (files in open tabs), the side bar keeps popping in,sliding back in...I never had anything like that in sublime until now. Have been using it for years. 
Maybe I have a plugin that causes it? But then again I have been using the same setup in all mu envs..

Comment: go to preferences and select setting user hope it will work

Comment: Did some more research into this an cant find any explanation! Very Strange. I might downgrade Sublime, maybe is something with the new build...

Comment: Nope. 
One thing maybe to note, I am running it on Bootcamp on a Mac.But then I have had it for a while, and didnt have this strange issue , before.
I might try to downgrade/reinstall Sublime. Just dont want to go trough the  hassle  setting it up again.

Comment: Just did it !!!! reinstalled it and the issue went away. 
I am reusing my previous settings and packages from 
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3 
folder.
So, I am using the same settings, but the issue is gone.
Thanks for trying to help out.

Comment: Actually, still having random keyboard behaviours, that activating the side bar, but is not as bad as before.

Comment: WOW!!!!!
This is killing me, the same behaviour is back.

Switching between open files and side bar keeps sliding in!!!!!! again
In addition to random key combinations triggers the same annoying behaviour.
For example 'ctrl + f' slides in the side bar.... and couple more other key combinations...

Checked the user defined key settings, deleted them, checked the default key settings and still nothing!!!!

This might cause me to abandon my favourite editor...

Comment: @AlimHasanov i will suggest you to use this nice Editor Atom
You will pray for me if you use this found at here
[download and description](https://atom.io/)

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.

I did resolve it! just uninstall package AutoHide Sidebar and SyncedSideBar.